# Where can we Rent/Ride ATVs and Off-Road Motorcycles near San José?

Tags: adventure, rental, costa-rica, off-road

We're in Costa Rica in the San José area (Santa Ana), and we are looking for a place to rent and ride ATVs and off-road motorcycles, perhaps in the mountains.

Are there any businesses in the area that offer off-road trails and rentals?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found two rental companies apparently located in San José, Costa Rica:

- [Wild Rider](http://www.wild-rider.com) (US$55-80 per day, minimum 3 days)
- [Costa Rica Motorcycle Tours](http://www.costaricamotorcycletours.com/) (US$90-145 per day)

Prices as of April 5, 2012.